# Utilising Python dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program which writes a text file containing names and some queries. The first four lines start by defining a parental figure on left and their children after the colon; think of it as a family tree if you will. The exercise asks us to use dictionaries to help solve this problem.

This is how the file starts off..

```
test_file = open('relationships.txt', 'w')
test_file.write('''Sue: Chad, Brenda, Harris
Charlotte: Tim
Brenda: Freddy, Alice
Alice: John, Dick, Harry

mother Sue
mother Charlotte
mother Brenda
mother Dick
''')
test_file.close()
```

The output should be ..

```
Mother not known
Mother not known
Sue
Alice
```

I'm unsure on how to create this `mother` query that checks to see which mother the child belongs to. I've tried a few things such as..

```
parents = {}

for line in lines[0:4]:
    parent, child = line.strip().split(':')

    if parent in parents:
        parents[parent] += str(child)
    else:
        parents[parent] = str(child)

print(parents)
```

I'm stuck at this point on how to then access and figure out whose mother is who. The only other way I can think of which is far less elegant would be to switch the key and value around to have a huge list of lines individually labelling every child's mother.

Comment: I have to ask -- what exactly do you think `str()` will do for you? `split()` is a method that's available on instances of `str` and returns a sequence of `str`. Thus, in this case, it's always true that `str(child)` == `child`.

Comment: Gave me a weird syntax error for some reason and that seemed to solve it..

Comment: I haven't managed to reproduce that. Removing the 'str()' in both those lines of your script gives no syntax error, and the behaviour is identical with and without the `str()`. Consider the possibility that you had managed to insert a strange character (for example, one of the non-ascii space characters, like this `　`, or this(``, which is one of the weirder cases -- its width is 0, so it's very difficult to detect.). Python can become confused. I just pasted that second character into your script, and Python immediately reported a SyntaxError: Invalid character in identifier.

Comment: haha, looks like StackOverflow also chokes on it. I wrote `@Androx` at the start of the above comment, but StackOverflow magically vanished it.. woah... EDIT: or maybe `@postauthor` is automatically removed, since they receive notification anyway.

Comment: @kampu Haha true, not sure what did it but I perfectly understand that there is no need for the `str()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually address your question of using **dictionaries**:

```
parentchild_map = {}
for line in lines:
    if ':' not in line:
         continue
    mother, multichildren = line.split(':')
    children = multichildren.strip().split(', ')
    parentchild_map[mother] = children
```

Then you can check for a match like this:

```
 for parent, children in parentchild_map.items():
     if child in children:
         print ("Mother is ", parent)
         break
 else:
     print ('Mother not known.')
```

(EDIT: added missing "break" in above code)

To make the lookup faster, you could generate a reverse dictionary ahead of time

```
 reversemap = {}
 for parent, children in parentchild_map.items():
     for child in children:
         reversemap[child] = parent
```

then you would be able to just go:

```
 mother = reversemap.get(child)
 if mother:
     print ('Mother is ', mother)
 else:
     print ('Mother unknown.')
```

Whichever query algorithm you chose, the first or second one, I expect you would put it in a function accepting a 'child' parameter, so you could easily do as many queries as you want.

Comment: How do I go about processing a whole list of names like specified in the text file I write. I can only have one name in the `child` variable yet it prints out four results. I'm still rather confused on this topic..

Comment: This does process a whole list of names. You just set 'lines' to a list of lines in your file. This is easy to get, because for any given file-object `f`, you can write `lines=f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: @Androx; What do you mean 'you can only have one name in the child variable'? You can have a bazillion names in the child variable, if it's a sequence.  Also, you say 'it prints out four results` -- what are you doing for that to happen? It prints out one line, for me, which looks like "Mother is Angela" (for example if I'm looking up the mother of Fred).

Comment: For example, if `child = 'Tom'` then my answer is `Mary
Mother not known.
Mother not known.
Mother not known.
` I'd like to try process the family tree in `lines[0:4]` then output the answers to the queries in `lines[5:9]` but if I add more values to `child`, the program doesn't like it.

Comment: I just realized I left out a line. see my edit... also 'if I add more values to child, the program doesn't like it`. That's because iteration doesn't work like that; if you want to iterate over multiple values you have to __do the iteration__, say with a `for` loop, not just expect the existing code to magically iterate!

Comment: That's what I'm ultimately aiming at achieving with this program; being able to process the queries and get an output like shown in the OP. Yeah, I understand that I need to do that it's just a matter of how.. I've tried to store variables from a `for` loop but I'm wondering why it won't work. This is what I have `child = set()
for line in lines[5:9]:
    lineedit = line.strip().replace('mother ', '')
    child.add(lineedit)`

Comment: @Androx: Having a `set` of children is okay (however, be aware that sets are unordered, so iterating over it may not match the order you added items in. You may want an ordinary `list` instead.). Once you have that list you can just use `for c in child:` with the next line being `    showmother(c)` (assuming that `showmother()` is the function which looks up the mother of a given child). Also consider renaming `child` -- since it's not a child, it's a sequence of children here.

Comment: I'm still bitterly confused.. perhaps it's how I have it laid out but I just can't seem to get the answer!

Comment: I've made a small edit to my answer that may clarify things. I've also pastebinned the code I am using, with comments, [here](http://pastebin.com/A2fwqPKY). Hope this helps. If you don't understand functions well yet, that may have contributed to your confusion.

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks a lot for your patience and guidance on this issue. I'll do my best to analyse the differences between your code and mine to see where I went wrong and hopefully I can understand this concept better moving forward. Thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

You should keep a list of children, not a single string:

```
for line in lines[0:4]:
    parent, child = line.strip().split(':')

    if parent in parents:
        parents[parent].append(child)
    else:
        parents[parent] = [child]
```

Now, you can iterate over the parents and just check for a particular child:

```
child = 'Peter'

for parent, children in parents.items():
    if child in children:
        print('Mother is', parent)
        break
else:
    print('Mother not known')
```

Building a dictionary that maps children to their parents would make the lookup faster.

Comment: I initially upvoted, but I realize that you actually specifically avoided the original question given in the post, which is about dictionaries rather than lists.

Comment: @Androx: Figure out why. The logic is sound. I suspect that you need to do a `child.strip()` or something in the first example.

Comment: @Androx: Also, you aren't splitting up the string with children into a list of individual children. You can use `children.split(', ')` to do that.